# Iframe content unavailable even after setting document.domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

According to the plethora of SO questions I have read, if I set my parent page's `document.domain` property to be the same as the IFrame `src` domain, I should be able to interact with the IFrame content.

So, I have my parent page which lives at `http://abc.example.com` and I'm loading an IFrame from `http://example.com`. In the parent domain I do `document.domain = "example.com"`.

However, when the IFrame is loaded and I try to access it I get: `Blocked a frame with origin abc.example.com from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

What is the correct method for getting the `document.domain`s to work?

Comment: Have had issues in the past getting document.domain to work just right...but many moons ago and I did get it resolved cross browser. Certainly has to be right at the top. But...depending on what you need to do might be able to use postMessage API. What is your use case?

Comment: I want to access a local installation of the JIRA API to get the current user's logged in name.

Comment: postMessage would be ideal for something like that

Comment: but that will require a change to the JIRA API pages - which is not an option for me.

Comment: Oh...I misunderstood. The only way document.domain, or any other cross domain iframe access is allowed is if you control the code in both pages. You can't load a page from jira site and access it

Comment: but the JIRA is a local installation on our local domain (`example.com/jira`) and my webapp is on `app.example.com`. So i thought i could set `document.domain` on my webapp to be `example.com`?

Comment: can you not slip a js block or script tag into that jira template? The `document.domain` is typically set inside the iframe to match parent. But if you were able to insert js could also use postMessage

Comment: what kind of JS block? If i manually call up the JIRA API page in my browser and do `document.domain` in the console it spits out `example.com` which is what im setting my parent to

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage